# Unable to find "SecurityMode" attribute in element in web.config of WCF service

Tags: wcf, binding, https, basichttpbinding

I am writing a WCF Service Application in Visual Studio 2010 using .NET Framework 4.0.

I am trying to implement BasicHttpBinding with HTTPS. I read in some example that I need to create a custom binding as follow and to set it as "bindingConfiguration" attribute while setting up an endpoint.

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding
configurationName="UsingHttps"
securityMode="Https"/>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

However, when I try to write similar in my web.config, the intellisense is not showing "configurationName" and "securityMode" attributes. What can be the reason here? Do I need to change any setting in Visual Studio IDE?

Any help on this, much appreciated.

Thanks

Nirman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got the attribute names wrong, and tried to set the security mode in the wrong place:

```
<binding name="myBindingName">
    <security mode="Transport">
        ...etc...
    </security>
</binding>
```

This old (July 2007!!) MSDN article has plenty of examples of both programmatic and static configuration of bindings, transport security, etc: [WCF Bindings In Depth](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineJuly2007en-us.chm) (the whole magazine is now packaged as a CHM download, but you can see the specified article directly online on [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20081223210236/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx)).

Comment: oh ok... will try out this one.. but i copied this from one eBook.. This ebook is targetted for .NET Framework.. that means, it was typo in Ebook...